# "if case" - Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer

Tags: swift, auth0

I updated my project from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3.0. Then, because a lot of different error I downgraded to Swift 2.3. Now, I'm having this error which I can't find the solution. Does anyone knows why I'm getting this error?

`Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer`

This is the function I'm using:

```
func credentials(values: [String: String], callback: Result<Credentials> -> ()) {
    guard
        let code = values["code"]
        else {
            let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            return callback(.Failure(error: AuthenticationError(string: string)))
        }
    let clientId = self.clientId
    Authentication(clientId: clientId, url: url)
        .tokenExchange(withCode: code, codeVerifier: verifier, redirectURI: redirectURL.absoluteString!)
        .start { result in
            // error is in if-case below:
            if case .Failure(let cause as AuthenticationError) = result, cause.description == "Unauthorized"{

                let error = WebAuthError.PKCENotAllowed("Please go to 'https://manage.auth0.com/#/applications/\(clientId)/settings' and set 'Token Endpoint Authentication Method' to 'None' to enable PKCE.")
                callback(Result.Failure(error: error))
            } else {
                callback(result)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The error means that the associated value `cause` can't be used as a bound variable. Use `if case let`

Comment: @vadian thank you for your help. I'm already using `let` when i'm creating `cause` variable... and when I put `let` next to `if case` the error remains the same... maybe I didn't get your point

Comment: This is my first swift project so I'm not familiar with

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try changing

```
let cause as AuthenticationError
```

to

```
let cause = cause as AuthenticationError
```

I had a similar problem and that solved it for me.